# Understanding conditional probability 3

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

The expectation of $x_0$ is 
$\mu = E(x_0) = m_0$

The expectation of $x_0$ given $\mu$ is
$x^f = E[x_0\mid \mu]=\mu$

Can someone explain how the $E[x_0\mid \mu] =\mu$? I am not able to understand how this is written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mu$ is a constant value.   The expectation of a random variable, given the value of some constant is just the expectation of the random variable.   It just happens *in this case* that the expectation evaluates to that constant.

There are many other cases.   Let $c$ be the speed of light, a constant value.   $\mathsf E(x_0\mid c) = \mathsf E(x_0) = \mu$

Comment: For instance, if $z_0 = x_0$  will $E ( z_0 \mid x^f) = \mu$ ?